I am stuck with Unity C# CameraControl Script
I am coding a simple TPS zombie game, and now I'm stuck with an issue with the camera controls. The X rotation works no problem, but the Y rotation is reversed; if I drag cursor to the bottom, my character looks up. How can I fix that?

public class KameraKontrol : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform hedef;
    public Vector3 hedefMesafe;
    [SerializeField]
    private float hassasiyet;
    float fareX, fareY;

    Vector3 objRot;
    public Transform karakterVucut;

    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        this.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(this.transform.position, hedef.position + hedefMesafe, Time.deltaTime * 10);
        fareX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * hassasiyet;
        fareY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * hassasiyet;
        if (fareY >= 25)
        {
            fareY = 25; 
        }
        if (fareY <= -40)
        {
            fareY = -40;
        }
        this.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(fareY, fareX, 0);
        hedef.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, fareX, 0);


        this.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(fareY, fareX, 0);
        hedef.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, fareX, 0);

        Vector3 gecici = this.transform.localEulerAngles;
        gecici.z = 0;
        gecici.y = this.transform.localEulerAngles.y;
        gecici.x = this.transform.localEulerAngles.x + 10;
        objRot = gecici;
        karakterVucut.transform.eulerAngles = objRot;
    }
}

With this code the Y rotation is reversed.

Just subtract the mouse delta from fareY instead of adding it to invert the direction:
fareX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * hassasiyet;
fareY -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * hassasiyet;

If you want the "inverted mouse" to be a boolean (so you can make it into a setting instead of being hardcoded), you can multiply by -1 as well:
public bool useInvertedMouse = false;

private void LateUpdate() {
  ...
  fareX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * hassasiyet;
  fareY -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * hassasiyet * (useInvertedMouse ? 1 : -1);
  ...
}

